# Extracting all .msg files from a .pst file

Tags: c#, mfc

Note: I was asked to create an app that extracts .msg files from a .pst file preferably in MFC. I was informed that they have tried to use other 3rd party apps but they all failed (don't ask me how) so that's why they are asking me to create an app to do this.

First question: I was told that MFC was the preferred language, so are there MFC libraries to support implementing this in MFC? If not, can C# do?

Second question: If yes, which libraries to use? If not, which C# libraries to use?

Comment: There's an app for that: Outlook... And I think it's even MFC at its roots...

Comment: the question is about creating an app, thanks for saying that Capt. Obvious

Comment: I just don't get why you want to climb a mountain, if you don't have to. I remember extracting all emails into separate files from Outlook itself...

Comment: So the full picture is: I was told that they've done that. Create a new account in Outlook, drag and drop things all mails there but they 'said' that when they are doing that, "it creates fault on the new .pst file". And off they go looking for other tools that could do this but all have failed. Now I don't know why they think that I could create a new app (that does similar function to those that failed) to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

[MSG .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/msg) (C# library). 
It does exactly what you need, extract all messages as .msg files from a .pst file.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to write your own application, then you *must* start by searching and downloading the PST specification. LMGTFY... Ah, you can find it on MSDN:

> [[MS-PST]: Outlook Personal Folders (.pst) File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Only then can you determine what tools you need for the job, and which programming languages will help you best.

---

It looks like a well specified binary format. So any language that will allow you to read binary files (both MFC and C# can do this well) will do the job. There may be third-party libraries available for reading .PST files, but you'll really have to search those yourself and evaluate them according to your criteria. For example:

- [NMapi - C# MAPI Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4007209/146622)

Comment: They way I think of the problem is, like when extracting elements from XML, I just need to include the .XML library and off I go extracting the elements from the XML file. If you get what I mean?

Comment: @Mikk Yes I know what you mean. But XML is a universally used well-defined versatile file format, and PST is not. You are already lucky it has a publicly available specification (most formats don't have one). You'll have to search for such a library yourself. You're probably not the first who wants to do this (e.g. look at open-source e-mail clients).